# Rally SDk2.0 rc3 PrefManager update method issue

Tags: sdk, rally

I had an app that worked fine with sdk 2.0rc3 namely updating a preference value with more strings. Recently this stopped working and when I investigated it turned out that if pref does not exist PrefManager.update method creates one with requested value correctly. But if I want to update already existing one then it fails to apply any sort of update.
Does anyone know if this is caused by the latest Rally changes on the platform?

Or maybe an idea what might be wrong?

```
_saveNewPrefs : function (prefValue){
    var sortedPrefs = prefValue;//_.sortby(prefValue,'keyword'); 
    var appPrefValueEncoded = Ext.JSON.encode(sortedPrefs);

    // resave entire pref again with new build
    var newPref = {};
    newPref[this.appPrefName] = appPrefValueEncoded;
                    console.log ('workspace', this.appWorkspace);

    console.log('newPref', newPref);
    Rally.data.PreferenceManager.update({
        settings: newPref,
        workspace: this.appWorkspace,
        success: function(updatedRecords, notUpdatedRecords) {
            console.log ('Pair saved', updatedRecords);
            console.log('this',this);

            this._displayGrid();
        },
        scope : this
    });
},
```

Error thrown is this
"Validation error: Preference.Name conflicts with buildList55 where buildList55 is the pre-existing pref name

Comment: So it turned out there is an error being thrown

Comment: did you figure out what was going on?  can you add a comment or an answer to this question in case anyone else also runs into this same issue?

Comment: no still no idea - I don't think issue is on my end. Here is the function that calls it and was working fine before with creating new pref or updating existing one - see above the updated post

Comment: What if you also add appID: this.getContext().getAppId() to the config object passed to PreferenceManager.update?

Comment: Thanks Kyle but after adding this the error is still the same
0: "Validation error: Preference.Name conflicts with buildList55 "
Rally.data.PreferenceManager.update({
            settings: newPref,
   appID: this.getContext().getAppId(),
            workspace: this.appWorkspace,
            success: function(updatedRecords, notUpdatedRecords) {
                console.log ('Pair saved', updatedRecords);
                //console.log('this',this);

                this._displayGrid();
            },
            scope : this 
        });

Comment: And I think this is because appID is undefined - -when I console output this 
console.log ('appID', this.getContext().getAppId());

result: appID undefined

Comment: Finally fixed it - so the issues was twofold - I needed to add the appID AND I needed to recreate the pref as the old one was someone locked for any updates since was updated without passing appID to the Pref Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it - so the issues was twofold - I needed to add the appID AND I needed to recreate the pref as the old one was someone locked for any updates since was updated without passing appID to the Pref Manager.